# iPhone 3.0 SDK vs iPhone 2.0 SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

is iPhone 3.0 SDK significantly different that I cannot use any books that were meant for iPhone 2.0 SDK?
Programming is pretty much the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally as everyone said above, changes to UITableView and few other items. 2.0 books still will be a great way to start.

Generally skip over any chapters with sound there is a new framework called AVAudioPlayer which makes playing sound sooooo much easier.

3.0 added a lot of extra frameworks which are real cool.

- CoreData which is quite complex but
  can be used for storing complex data.
- MapKit has been added which allows
  you to add google maps into you
  application. It also features reverse
  GeoCoding which means you can give
  the map your lat,long and it will
  give you an address which is way
  cool.
- Now you can interact with the    user
  iPhone Music Library and play
  their music in your app.
- You can also    access the proximity sensor
- cut/copy/paste,
- video
- shake gesture
- push notification
- in-app purchasing

.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 2.0 books should give you the basic idea of how to structure your code, however you will miss out on some of the nice new things such as the availability of CoreData.  A few things have changed with some of the controls such as UITableView, however you will get deprecation warnings from the compiler if you try to do things the old way.

Answer (score 1):

The language is the same, with the addition of some new classes and a few changes to old ones. Your 2.0 books will be fine. If you're not using new features that were added in 3.0, there's almost no difference.

Answer (score 0):

So far the biggest difference I found in terms of features that were available at 2.0 is changes made to Table views, specifically to table view cells. Apple added a lot of nice features that are commonly used every where that you had to write yourself. In 3.0 some of those are given to you.

So my advice is don't worry about using 2.0 books but when you start working on something also consult the SDK's documentation to see if there are any interesting things not mentioned in the book (I guess that would be a good advice even if the SDK didn't change).